# Haskell terminology: meaning of type vs. data type, are they synonyms?

Tags: haskell, terminology

I'm reading the book: Haskell School of Expression and on page 56, at the beginning of chapter 5, I read the terms "polymorphic data types" and "polymorphic types".

Are these two terms refer to the same concept?

Are they synonyms ?

Or is there any difference between the two? If yes, what?

Comment: As a rough comparison with C - if you know that language - is that `data` is like `struct` and `union` combined, and `type` is like `typedef`. However, haskell data types are much more potent that their C counterparts (`data` allows many more constructs, given all the available extensions).

Comment: @didierc the rough comparison would be a tagged union really, but like you said they are a bit more than that

Comment: @Wes, yes I was thinking about that, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A **type** (in Haskell) is a piece of syntax which can meaningfully be put right of `::` to classify an expression left of `::`. Each syntactic component of a type is itself classified by a **kind**, where the kind of types (which classify expressions) is `*`. *Some people are happy to use the word "type" to refer to any component of the type syntax, whether or not its kind allows it to classify expressions.*

The syntax of types can be extended by various declaration forms.

1. A **type synonym**, e.g., `type Foo x y z = [x] -> IO (y, z)`, adds type components of fully applied form `Foo` *x* *y* *z*, which expand macro-fashion in accordance with their defining equation.
2. A **data** declaration, e.g., `data Goo x y z = ThisGoo x | ThatGoo (Goo y z x)` introduces a fresh **type constructor** symbol `Goo` to the syntax of types, which is used to build the types which classify values generated by the **data constructors**, here `ThisGoo` and `ThatGoo`.
3. A **newtype** declaration, e.g., `newtype Noo x y z = MkNoo (x, [y], z)` makes a copy of an existing type which is distinguished from the original in the syntax of types.

A type is **polymorphic** if it contains **type variables** which can be substituted with other type components: the values classified by polymorphic types can be **specialized** to any substitution instance of the type variables. E.g. append `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` works on lists whose elements have the same type, but any type will do. Values with polymorphic types are often referred to as "polymorphic values".

Sometimes, "data type" is used to mean, quite simply, a type introduced by a `data` declaration. In this sense, all data types are types, but not all types are data types. Examples of types which are not data types include `IO ()` and `Int -> Int`. Also, `Int` is not a data type in *this* sense: it is a hardwired **primitive** type. For the avoidance of doubt, some people call these types **algebraic** data types, because the constructors give an algebra, meaning "a bunch of operations for building values by combining other values". A "polymorphic data type" is a data type with type variables in it, such as `[(a, Bool)]`, by contrast with `[Int]`. Sometimes people talk about "declaring a polymorphic data type" or say things like "`Maybe` is a polymorphic data type" when they really just mean that the type constructor has parameters (and can thus be used to form polymorphic types): pedantically, one does declare a polymorphic data type, but not any old polymorphic datatype, rather a type constructor applied to formal parameters).

Of course, all first-class values classified by types are in some sense "data", and in Haskell, types are not used to classify anything which is not a first-class value, so in that looser sense, every "type" is a "data type". The distinction becomes more meaningful in languages where there are things other than data which have types (e.g., methods in Java).

Informal usage is often somewhere in the middle and not very well defined. People are often driving at some sort of distinction between functions or processes and the sort of stuff (the "data") on which they operate. Or they might think of data as being "understood in terms of the way they're made" (and exposing their representation, e.g. by pattern matching) rather than "understood in terms of the way they're used". This last usage of "data" sits a little uncomfortably with the notion of an **abstract** data type, being a type which hides the representation of the underlying stuff. Representation-hiding abstract data types thus contrast rather strongly with representation-exposing algebraic data types, which is why it is rather unfortunate that "ADT" is casually used as an abbreviation for both.

The upshot, I'm afraid, is vague.

Comment: Can you add an example of abstract data type w.r.t Haskell ? Is List an abstract data type according to this definition ?

Comment: Lists are not an abstract datatype in Haskell, as their representation is exposed: you can access them by pattern matching. The library type `Set a` is an example of an abstract data type: you get an interface (with an empty set, union, intersection, various tests, etc) but you can't get at the actual representation (which could just use lists, in fact, but as far as I know is really some nifty binary tree thing).

Comment: So the answer is that nobody really knows the difference, if I understand it correctly. Unfortunately Hudak does not define the term “data type" in his book but still uses it, I would have expected more preciseness from this highly respected author.

Comment: I think the answer is not that nobody knows the difference but instead that "data type" is simply not always a technical term. Or rather it's many. And often it's precise meaning isn't worth capturing. The answer here does capture, fairly comprehensively, all precise meanings I can think of though.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `data type` and `type` are synonymous.  However, I will admit that confusion can arise because Haskell has two keywords `data` and `type` that perform two very different functions.  To try to keep the distinction clear, it's important to be mindful of the context.  Whenever you're talking about the *types in a signature* or *types in general*, the terms "data types" and "types" almost always refer to the same thing.  Whenever you're talking about *declaring types in code*, there can be a difference.

A type declared with `data` is a new, user-defined type, so you can do things like

```
data Status = Ready | NotReady | Exploded
```

Where `Ready`, `NotReady` and `Exploded` are new constructors not included in Haskell.

On the other hand, there is the `type` keyword that simply creates an *alias* to an existing type:

```
type Status = String

ready, notReady, exploded :: Status
ready = "Ready"
notReady = "NotReady"
exploded = "Exploded"
```

Here, the `Status` is simply an alias for `String`, and anywhere you use `String` you can use a `Status` and vice-versa.  There aren't any constructors, just pre-built values to use.  This approach is far less safe and if you use something like this you *will* run into bugs at some point.  `type` declarations are commonly used to make certain arguments more clear about what they're for, such as

```
type FilePath = String
```

This is a built-in alias in GHC, and if you see a function

```
doSomething :: FilePath -> IO ()
```

Then you know immediately to pass it a file name, compared to

```
doSomething :: String -> IO ()
```

You have no idea what this function does, other than "something".  They're also commonly used to reduce typing, such as:

```
type Point = (Double, Double)
```

Now you can use `Point` instead of `(Double, Double)` in your type signatures, which is shorter to write and more readable.

---

To summarize, `data` declares an entirely new type, completely custom just for you, and `type` should be renamed `alias` so that people stop getting confused about them when they first approach Haskell.

Comment: IMHO `type` is the only one of `data/type/newtype` that make sense. It's the others that are syntactically confusing because of the nonsensical use of `=` and the mixing of type-level and term-level identifiers. `type` is a straightforward type-level natural function (natural transformation)

Answer (score 0):

`type` and `data type` refers to the same concept, and so are `polymorphic type` and `polymorphic data type`.

To illustrate a case where both phrases may be used altogether (without any difference on meaning), consider this expression

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

I can say that I just defined a polymorphic data type `Maybe`, with polymorphic type parameter `a`.