# The type checker is allowing a very wrong type replacement, and the program still compiles

Tags: haskell, types

While trying to debug an issue in my program (2 circles with an equal radius are being drawn to different sizes using Gloss`*`), I stumbled across a strange situation. In my file that handles objects, I have the following definition for a `Player`:

```
type Coord = (Float,Float)
data Obj =  Player  { oPos :: Coord, oDims :: Coord }
```

and in my main file, which imports Objects.hs, I have the following definition:

```
startPlayer :: Obj
startPlayer = Player (0,0) 10
```

This happened due to me adding and changing fields for player, and forgetting to update `startPlayer` after (its dimensions were determined by a single number to represent a radius, but I changed it to a `Coord` to represent (width,height); in case I ever make the player object a non-circle).

The amazing thing is, the above code compiles, and runs, despite the second field being of the wrong type.

I first thought that maybe I had different versions of the files open, but any changes to any files were reflected in the compiled program.

Next I thought that maybe `startPlayer` wasn't being used for some reason. Commenting out `startPlayer` yields a compiler error though, and even stranger, changing the `10` in `startPlayer` causes an appropriate response (changes the starting size of the `Player`); again, despite it being of the wrong type. To make sure that it's reading the data definition correctly, I inserted a typo into the file, and it gave me an error; so I am looking at the correct file.

I tried pasting the 2 snippets above into their own file, and it spat out the expected error that the second field of `Player` in `startPlayer` is incorrect.

What could possibly allow this to happen? You'd think that this is the very thing that Haskell's type checker should prevent.

---

`*` The answer to my original problem, two circles of supposedly equal radius being drawn to different sizes, was that one of the radii was actually negative.

Comment: As @Cubic noted, you should definitely report this problem to the Gloss maintainers. Your question nicely illustrates how a library's improper orphan instance messed up *your* code.

Comment: Done. Is it possible to exclude instances? They may require it for the library to function, but I don't need it. I also noticed that they defined Num Color. It's only a matter of time before that snags me.

Comment: @Cubic Well, too late. And I only downloaded it a week or so ago using an updated, up-to-date Cabal; so it should be current.

Comment: Yeah. My comment was moot anyway - for one, it was wrong (I was just being blind) and I just checked myself. The instance is definitely where your ghci output says it is.

Comment: Well, considering you solved it like 10 minutes after it was asked, you cant be that blind. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianConkle There's a chance the author of gloss didn't understand what TypeSynonymInstances does. In any case, this really needs to go away (either make `Point` a `newtype` or use other operator names ala `linear`)

Comment: @Cubic: TypeSynonymInstances isn't that bad on its own (although not completely harmless), but when you combine it with OverlappingInstances things get very fun.

Comment: @Harry Stoteles Ha, that's petty, but I suppose it helps clean up the site; **if** that was your intention.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The only way this could possibly compile is if there exists a `Num (Float,Float)` instance. This isn't provided by the standard library, although it is possible that one of the libraries you're using added it for some insane reason. Try loading up your project in ghci and see if `10 :: (Float,Float)` works, then try `:i Num` to find out where the instance is coming from, and then yell at whoever defined it.

Addendum: There is no way to turn off instances. There isn't even a way to *not* export them from a module. If this were possible, it would lead to even *more* confusing code. The only real solution here is to not define instances like that.

Comment: WOW. `10 :: (Float, Float)` yields `(10.0,10.0)`, and `:i Num` contains the line `instance Num Point -- Defined in ‘Graphics.Gloss.Data.Point’` (`Point` is Gloss's alias of Coord). Seriously? Thank you. That saved me from a sleepless night.

Comment: @Carcigenicate While it seems frivolous to allow such instances, the reason it's allowed is so that developers can write their own instances of `Num` where it makes sense, such as an `Angle` data type that constrains a `Double` between `-pi` and `pi`, or if someone wanted to write a data type representing quaternions or some other more complex numeric type this feature is very convenient.  It also follows the same rules as `String`/`Text`/`ByteString`, allowing these instances makes sense from an ease-of-use point of view, but it can be misused as in this case.

Comment: @bheklilr I understand the need for allowing instances of Num. The "WOW" stemmed from a few things. I didn't know you could create instances of type aliases, creating a Num instance of a Coord just seems counter intuitive, and that I didn't think of it. Oh well, lesson learned.

Comment: You can work around your problem with the orphaned instance from your library by using a `newtype` declaration for `Coord` instead of a `type`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I believe you need [-XTypeSynonymInstances](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#id598783) to allow instances for type synonyms, but that isn't necessary to make the problematic instance. An instance for `Num (Float, Float)` or even `(Floating a) => Num (a,a)` would not require the extension but would result in the same behavior.

Comment: The instance is being removed. I submitted a PR and it has been accepted.

Answer (score 66):

Haskell's type checker is being reasonable. The problem is that the authors of a library you're using have done something... less reasonable.

The brief answer is: Yes, `10 :: (Float, Float)` is perfectly valid if there's an instance `Num (Float, Float)`. There's nothing "very wrong" about it from the compiler's or the language's perspective. It just doesn't square with our intuition about what numeric literals do. Since you're used to the type system catching the sort of error you made, you're justifiably surprised and disappointed!

### `Num` instances and the `fromInteger` problem

You're surprised that the compiler accepts `10 :: Coord`, i.e. `10 :: (Float, Float)`. It's reasonable to assume that numeric literals like `10` will be inferred to have "numeric" types. Out of the box, numeric literals can be interpreted as `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, or `Double`. A tuple of numbers, with no other context, doesn't seem like a number in the way those four types are numbers. We're not talking about [`Complex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex).

Fortunately or unfortunately, however, Haskell is a very flexible language. The standard specifies that an integer literal like `10` will be interpreted as `fromInteger 10`, which has type `Num a => a`. So `10` could be inferred as *any* type that's had a `Num` instance written for it. I explain this in a bit more detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515512/1186208).

So when you posted your question, an experienced Haskeller immediately spotted that for `10 :: (Float, Float)` to be accepted, there must be an instance like `Num a => Num (a, a)` or `Num (Float, Float)`. There's no such instance in the `Prelude`, so it must have been defined somewhere else. Using `:i Num`, you quickly spotted where it came from: the `gloss` package.

### Type synonyms and orphan instances

But hold on a minute. You're not using any `gloss` types in this example; why did the instance in `gloss` affect you? The answer comes in two steps.

First, [a type synonym introduced with the keyword `type` does not create a new type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24826657/1186208). In your module, writing `Coord` is simply shorthand for `(Float, Float)`. Likewise in [`Graphics.Gloss.Data.Point`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.2.2/docs/src/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Point.html), `Point` means `(Float, Float)`. In other words, your `Coord` and `gloss`'s `Point` are literally equivalent.

So when the `gloss` maintainers chose to write `instance Num Point where ...`, they also made your `Coord` type an instance of `Num`. That's equivalent to `instance Num (Float, Float) where ...` or `instance Num Coord where ...`.

(By default, Haskell doesn't allow type synonyms to be class instances. The `gloss` authors had to enable a pair of language extensions, `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances`, to write the instance.)

Second,  this is surprising because it's an *orphan instance*, i.e. an instance declaration `instance C A` where both `C` and `A` are defined in other modules. Here it's particularly insidious because each part involved, i.e. `Num`, `(,)`, and `Float`, comes from the `Prelude` and is likely to be in scope everywhere.

Your expectation is that `Num` is defined in `Prelude`, and tuples and `Float` are defined in `Prelude`, so everything about how those three things work is defined in `Prelude`. Why would importing a completely different module change anything? Ideally it wouldn't, but orphan instances break that intuition.

(Note that GHC warns about orphan instances—the authors of `gloss` specifically overrode that warning. That should have raised a red flag and prompted at least a warning in the documentation.)

### Class instances are global and cannot be hidden

Furthermore, class instances are *global*: any instance defined in any module that is transitively imported from *your* module will be in context and available to the typechecker when doing instance resolution. This makes global reasoning convenient, because we can (usually) assume that a class function like `(+)` will always be the same for a given type. However, it also means that local decisions have global effects; defining a class instance irrevocably changes the context of downstream code, with no way to mask or conceal it behind module boundaries.

You [cannot use import lists to avoid importing instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731340/1186208). Similarly, you cannot avoid exporting instances from modules you define.

This is a problematic and much-discussed area of the Haskell language design. There's a fascinating discussion of related issues in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1id0p7/backpack_retrofitting_haskell_with_interfaces/cb3eb2n). See, for instance, Edward Kmett's comment on allowing visibility control for instances: "You basically throw out the correctness of almost all of the code I have written."

(By the way, as [this answer demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744568/1186208), you *can* break the global-instance assumption in some regards by using orphan instances!)

### What to do—for library implementers

Think twice before implementing `Num`. You cannot work around the `fromInteger` problem—no, defining `fromInteger = error "not implemented"` does *not* make it better. Will your users be confused or surprised—or worse, never notice—if their integer literals are accidentally inferred to have the type you're instantiating? Is providing `(*)` and `(+)` that critical—particularly if you have to hack it?

Consider using alternative arithmetical operators defined in a library like Conal Elliott's [`vector-space`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) (for types of kind `*`) or Edward Kmett's [`linear`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) (for types of kind `* -> *`). This is what I tend to do myself.

Use `-Wall`. Do not implement orphan instances, and do not disable the orphan instance warning.

Alternately, follow the lead of `linear` and many other well-behaved libraries, and provide orphan instances in a separate module ending in `.OrphanInstances` or [`.Instances`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.12.1/docs/Linear-Instances.html). And *do not import that module from any other module*. Then users can import the orphans explicitly if they would like.

If you find yourself defining orphans, consider asking upstream maintainers to implement them instead, if possible and appropriate. I used to frequently write the orphan instance `Show a => Show (Identity a)`, until they added it to `transformers`. I may even have raised a bug report about it; I don't remember.

### What to do—for library consumers

You don't have many options. Reach out—politely and constructively!—to the library maintainers. Point them to this question. They may have had some special reason to write the problematic orphan, or they may just not realize.

More broadly: Be aware of this possibility. This is one of the few areas of Haskell where there are true global effects; you'd have to check that every module you import, and every module *those* modules import, doesn't implement orphan instances. Type annotations may sometimes alert you to problems, and of course you can use `:i` in GHCi to check.

Define your own `newtype`s instead of `type` synonyms if it's important enough. You can be pretty sure nobody will mess with them.

If you're having frequent problems deriving from an open-source library, you can of course make your own version of the library, but maintenance can quickly become a headache.